# Exporting large geometry node network out as an image

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I created a "large" geometry node network tree and would like to export the entire Geometry Node network out as one large png or image that is **readable**.  How can this be done?  An option to do this would be very helpful to review your node setup. Does such a thing exist?  (And yes, I know I can put things in groups to compress them down, the goal is to review / see the entire node setup all at once even if I have to scroll through the image.)

Example: of the type of node network.
[image: img1]

The size isn't an issue at the moment since I would be using **[pureref](https://www.pureref.com/)** to view the image.

Comment: This feature was mentioned by a dev on DevTalk as something they should provide at some point down the line, but it's anyone's guess when that might actually happen. There's no native way to do this, afaik. There's this free add-on but I never used it: https://yeetusblenditus.gumroad.com/l/PrtNd Or you could zoom in, go screenshotting in a grid and stitch them together in a panorama-maker program I guess.

Comment: @Thanks Kuboå unfortunately that won't work for me..I use Linux..  I guess I'll have to wait.

Comment: It says "Works on Linux and Mac only for Blender 2.93 or above"? Did you try it?

Comment: I didn't try the portable windows version (I'm using 3.1 Linux) I read the docs and it said  - For Blender 3.0 or above, a custom build of blender (along with PrintNodes v1.1.4) is required which has been uploaded here.  Then when I clicked the link.  
Works with 3.0 (or above) but not on the official builds. 

You'll need to download and use BlenderForPrintNodes.zip (portable windows only build, based on Blender 3.1a. 

Doesn't support CUDA/Optix and is only meant to be used for PrintNodes) for PrintNodes to properly work until there's a proper fix available..

Comment: "normally" you would try to use nodegroups even if you don't reuse them (so you only use them once) they can drastically improve the readability. Just an example you get this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vsa3.png instead of this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9R5D.jpg of course you get then still the details of the nodegroups but the "main" node tree is much more readable - in my opinion. That's why you use functions in programming languages. It is exactly the same. The functions structure the code and you can name them and so it is much easier to understand the code.

Comment: Workaround: Plug in more monitors, expand the window to all available monitors, use "Save Screenshot (Editor)" to capture the largest possible area. Repeat the screenshot if it is still not enough and paste the images together in an image editor.

Answer (score 1):

A solution outside of Blender is to set your system to a custom resolution. This works on [Nvidia](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/759/%7E/custom-resolutions), [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/dh-032), and [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056144/graphics/legacy-graphics.html) systems, hopefully other systems too. Set your resolution high enough and you should be good to go.