# How to retrieve vector-based image from Geometry Nodes tree?

Tags: geometry-nodes, export, image

As a student I am currently researching the opportunities and challenges of using Geometry Nodes in the field of work of a built environment engineer. The past months I made some Geometry Nodes trees which can be used in the design process.

I would like to share my work on the Geometry Nodes in a pdf-file. Since I am writing this paper in Adobe InDesign it is preferable to use vector-based images. I already discovered the Save Screenshot (editor) function from the Window tab in the Info Window ribbon. Unfortunately, this function only gives the option to export a screenshot as a raster-based image.

**Questions and desired solution**

*Is it possible to export the Geometry Nodes tree as an vector-based image file?*

Desired file format:

- .pdf
- .svg

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and input!

Comment: My thought is: no, it's not possible to export the node tree as SVG with the UI. But you can read the node tree with Python easily. This includes the location, names, slots, and the connections of the nodes. (e.g.  *bpy.data.node_groups['My Nodes'].nodes['Normal'].location[0]* is the X position of the *Normal* GN node in *My Nodes* tree. This info can be used to create an [SVG file](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#TypesOfGraphicsElements) (which is only a text file). I guess it's not hard to do, just a lot of work. Have you searched for an add-on? Maybe someone did it already...?

Comment: related quesiton: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/258966/107598